# No module named 'openpyxl.styles'

Tags: python

I am witing a dataframe using the below code:

```
with pd.ExcelWriter('/Users/Nitin/Desktop/org') as writer:
    df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='df1', index=False)
    df2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='df2', index=False)
    df3.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='df3', index=False)
    df4.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='df4', index=False)
```

I get the error: No module named 'openpyxl.styles'

Comment: did you install and import openpyxl: `pip install openpyxl`?

Comment: yes..version is openpyxl==1.7.0

Comment: Try updating it to a later version it works with **openpyxl==2.6.1**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try updating 
`pip install -U openpyxl==2.6.1`

Then you can check:

```py
import openpyxl
openpyxl.styles
```

Should return something like:

```sh
<module 'openpyxl.styles' from ....>
```